# accessing property file in struts programmatically

Tags: struts, resourcebundle

I am trying to access the propertfile for customizing the message , in struts java file. I would like to know how to access the key in property file programmatically inside java file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your structs action class  :

```
    String fileName ="filepname"; //property fileName 
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(fis); //load the property file

    String posterVarName = props.getProperty("property"); //get property
```

Comment: Thanks code buzz, iam trying to implement it using struts not java code.

Comment: @Sachin : you can write this code in your action class with no difference..!!